# An Amazing Palindrome

Tags: word, language

My friend told me she was thinking of a word.

It can be seen left to right, right to left and upside down by the English, French and Japanese and still be *palindrome* (A sequence of characters which reads the same backward or forward).

What is this mysterious word?

Comment: Thanks to the anonymous DV for such constructive criticism.

Comment: Downvoting because of the issues raised in the accepted answer's comments. Lateral thinking != poorly worded puzzles.

Comment: I have voted to close my own question. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: -1 as this is a very cheap trick and is not funny or entertaining or insightful. As BmyGuest and DylanSp have said, tagging such a cheap trick [lateral-thinking] or [enigmatic-puzzles] does not save it.

Comment: @RosieF What is the current issue? Please provide better feedback.

Comment: I think it is rather clever, actually.  It isn't a joke, but it *is* a riddle.  But he does sort of give away the answer when he leaves out the article by saying, "...and still be *palindrome*..." .

Comment: Actually, *palindrome* spelled backward is not *palindrome* - it is *semordnilap* which is similar to a palindrome, but different.  Whereas a palindrome backward spells itself, a semordnilap backward will spell another word.  So actually, if you think if it this way, the answer can't be palindrome....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The word is ............

> Palindrome 
>  The word "Palindrome" in whatever language or orientation always means "Palindrome".

**OP's note**

The main clue that I thought would be picked up is

> the 'grammatical error' of *still be palindrome*, rather than *be a palindrome*.
>  
>  It is quite similar to 'what word in the English language is always spelt incorrectly?', but in a disguise.

The rest is pretty much self explanatory,

> since no matter how you choose to look at a word, the word will always be the same.

Comment: IT is indeed. Explanation?

Comment: Explanation added.

Comment: Just added some notes if you don't mind.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/169/

Comment: You cannot, in fact, read "palindrome" in (say) Thai and have it "still be palindrome", because "palindrome" is not a Thai word nor even made out of characters used in the Thai writing system.

Comment: I did involve the lateral-thinking tag for that exact reason.

Comment: @Inazuma The **lateral-thinking** tag is not a 'free-for-all'-token to fix up ill-defined questions or puzzles. It is indeed *very hard* to come up with a trick-question so that it still manages to 'catch you' but at the otherhand does not allow cheap loop holes. That is, why *good* trick-question-puzzles are *extremely rare*. I think, the posted question as it is, does not meet needed PuzzlingSE standards (yet). *Trick questions* rarely work in this format.

Comment: @BmyGuest If I inscribe the letters 'p a l i n d r o m e' 
they will be the same letters, no matter what language you speak, even to a dog. But yes, I will put more effort into my puzzles. I was aware that this might be ill-received in the first place, hence why I threw out such obvious hints (because I didn't want to use up too much time).

Comment: @Inazuma: Being "the same letters" to a dog is not the same as reading the word *in dog language* (even if such existed). A puzzle whose answer doesn't actually meet the question's criteria isn't excused by "lateral thinking."

Comment: This reminds me of the old joke, "What's black and white and green all over?" "I don't know." "A penguin!" "But a penguin's not green." "I know, I just threw that in to make it harder."

Comment: @LarsH, the version I heard of that one is actually good: "What do you get when you cross a cat, a bag of cement, and a lemon?" "I don't know."  "A sourpuss!"  "What about the cement?"  "I just threw that in to make it hard."

Comment: I think the question is wrong because "palindrome" would have to be in quotes to make it grammatically correct, and that would give away the answer. Perhaps this puzzle works when verbally spoken in a language without articles.

Comment: There were many things wrong with the grammar. That was the whole idea. But I have voted to close my own question. Thanks.

Comment: @LarsH I have now edited the puzzle

Comment: *palindromatic* perhaps?

Comment: @Inazuma, you've been very gracious in responding to criticism.

Comment: @LarsH There was no *constructive* criticism here, but as I said, thanks for your opinion.

Comment: I take back my previous comment.

Comment: @LarsH if you wish to take back your previous comment, you can delete it by pressing the little cross next to it :)

Comment: There can be a difference between deleting a comment, and taking it back.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are

> "O" and "I"

both of which kinda meet the conditions ... but "*any* language"? Neither of those would make much sense to someone whose only language is, say, Mandarin Chinese.

Comment: That was my thinking after I my first guess too.. Also "X" should be on the list too, shouldnt it?

Comment: My imaginary friend has also said that these are not the words.

Comment: I is the closest guess so far, since it is actually the character for 'one' in Chinese. But X and O are not actual words.

Comment: Other candidates for up/down are d/p  if you take 180 rotation not mirroring.

Comment: @Inazuma: "O" is an English word: [it is an older spelling of "oh" (the exclamation), and also means "a shape like the capital O"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/o?q=O).

Comment: Yup. And I think most languages have an exclamation like "O", if only because it's a noise people often make :-). (In English it's also used as an explicit indication of the vocative: "O Inazuma, hear my plea" or whatever.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I have upvoted this answer, what more do you want me to do?

Comment: Er, nothing? I mean, I suppose you could don sackcloth and ashes and walk around for a week carrying a sign saying "I posted an unsound puzzle on puzzling.stackoverflow.com" but I don't think that would do any particular good :-). ... If you're referring to my "O Inazuma, hear my plea", it was just an example sentence. No subtext intended.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I have now edited the puzzle

Answer (score 3):

From the edit:

> The word is ten letters long.

But the word you're thinking of **does not** have ten letters in every language! I think we're being cheated here...

Comment: The word is ten letters long (in English).

Answer (score 3):

["lol"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/lol) written such that the "o" is the height of the "l"s and the "l"s are written as just lines. This can be mirrored on both Y and X without changing the meaning, and a word can be imported and read from any language. For example, "What does domo mean in Esperanto?" Or the equivalent, "Kion signifas house signifas en la angla ?"

edit: This works unless your "hint" is a requirement.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This answer would have worked before the hints were posted. Generally, they are taken as rules and are sometimes used to narrow down questions that would otherwise be too broad, having a lot of good answers.

Comment: To be fair, a hint that is hidden should have no effect on the meaning of a puzzle. No problem ^voting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Was it...

> her name?
>  Lets say her name is Anna.. that would be a palindrome and I'd guess it wouldnt differ in any other languages since names arent translated most of the time.

Second guess after reading the comment of the OP

> maybe "SOS"? If you turn "s" upside down you'll get "s"

Comment: Not the same upside down though. Also names can be translated.

Comment: Almost thought that might've worked, but A) I don't think SOS is a proper word and B) http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/sos SOS is different in some languages

Comment: Only in the same sense as that in which the "correct" answer is different in some (in fact, most) languages.

Comment: maybe it is lol

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Maybe so. I should have paid more attention. Apologies.

Comment: SOS is the internaltional help signal it it the same in all languages. maybe not a word though.

Comment: Sorry to upset you, but in Hebrew this word isn't a palindrome since the last letter is changed in this case: אנה

Answer (score 2):

Simple

> She lying to you.There are  6000+ languages in the world and there is no such word as she describe.

Comment: My friend is aghast. She promises that there is.

Comment: @Inazuma Hmm. I might be wrong here, but I think that not even all languages can be written with the same character sets. I think there is even one which can not be written at all. That would strenthen Javy's point. How sure is "your friend" about the "all" in "all languages" ?

Comment: I have updated my post. The word does exist.